# Insert a code inside .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery 1.3.2 and I am modifying a cart module to better suit my needs. I found a function which I think should be what I am looking for.

```
function ajaxCartReloadCartView() {
  if (jQuery('#cart-form-pane').length) { 
    jQuery('#cart-form-pane').parent().load(Drupal.settings.uc_ajax_cart.SHOW_VIEW_CALLBACK, ajaxCartReloadCartViewSuccess );
  }
}
```

Would it be possible to insert code before and after function ajaxCartReloadCartViewSuccess?
I neeed to insert for example this code $("#cart-block-contents-ajax").removeClass("xxx");

Comment: Can you not just call `removeClass` in `ajaxCartReloadCartViewSuccess`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be just to wrap the function with a closure. Like this:

```
function ajaxCartReloadCartView() {
  if (jQuery('#cart-form-pane').length) { 
      jQuery('#cart-form-pane').parent().load(Drupal.settings.uc_ajax_cart.SHOW_VIEW_CALLBACK, 
          function (response,status,xhr) {
             $("#cart-block-contents-ajax").removeClass("xxx");
             ajaxCartReloadCartViewSuccess(response,status,xhr);
             // some other code
          });
      }
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to modify the original *ajaxCartReloadCartViewSucces* function.

EDIT: I don't know what exactly you're handling in this success functions, I took those params (response,status,xhr) from jQuery docs.